# What happens when the determinant of the Jacobian is zero?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f \colon \Bbb R^n \rightarrow \Bbb R^n$ be a continuously differentiable function.

Let $f'(x)$ denote the Jacobian matrix of $f$ at the point $x \in \Bbb R^n$.

I would like to show that if $f$ is one-to-one, then $\exists$ $a \in \Bbb R^n$ such that det$f'(a) \neq 0$.

When $n=1$, this result is a consequence of the Mean Value Theorem.

For larger $n$, I assume we will need some version of either the Inverse Function Theorem or the Implicit Function Theorem.

Thank you for your thoughts!

Comment: Nevermind, I believe this is an easy consequence of the constant rank theorem.